# ReferenceError: connect is not defined when executing node server.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am new to Nodejs and AngularJS. I have researched this error on your website and not been able to find an answer. I am working from the book, Pro AngularJS by Adam Freeman, Apress. After reading the post by Sheraz (nodejs connect cannot find static, Jun 21 '14) and the answer by dylants, I have done option 2, npm install serve-static. I updated my server.js code thus:

```
var connect = require('connect'),
serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var app = connect();
app.use(serveStatic("C:\wamp\www\Projects\ProAngularJS"));
app.listen(5000);
```

When I type "node C:\wamp\www\Projects\ProAngularJS\server.js" The error I get looks like this:

```
C:\wamp\www\Projects\ProAngularJS\server.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var app = connect(
);
                                                                    ^

ReferenceError: connect is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wamp\www\Projects\ProAngularJS\server.js:1:73)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
at node.js:968:3
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this error. Maybe I didn't install node correctly?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thx,
Khthulhu

Comment: do you have connect installed using 'npm i' and it shows up in the 'node_modules' folder?

Comment: Judging by the error message, it looks like the script you're executing does not match the code you've posted. Are you sure you are executing the right script and/or that you have saved your changes?

Comment: So I did the npm i connect command and I got this in return:

C:\Users\Condo>npm i connect

connect@3.4.1 node_modules\connect

├── utils-merge@1.0.0

├── parseurl@1.3.1

├── debug@2.2.0 (ms@0.7.1)

└── finalhandler@0.4.1 (escape-html@1.0.3, unpipe@1.0.0, on-finished@2.3.0)

Is that what I'm supposed to get back? Because I cannot find the connect module.

Comment: code is right. I get back:
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'connect'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wamp\www\Projects\ProAngularJS\server.js:19:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)

Comment: So I uninstalled nodejs and re-installed it in the admin user folder since my computer would not allow me to install connect into the node_modules folder from anywhere in Program Files(x86)/nodejs...because the error msgs seemed to indicate I should retry the command as admin. I installed the connect module into the correct location in the admin folder but the node C:\wamp\www\Projects\ProAngularJS\server.js command still returns error Error: Cannot find module 'connect'...blah blah blah. Kind of at a loss here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check whether you have connect module in node_modules, if not install it using npm. Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try that, thx. Does npm command require me to be online in order to install modules?

Comment: Nope. I tried several things. Couldn't install the connect module into the correct folder in program files (x86), and when I installed node into a different location, it wouldn't let me install it there either.